# How many times do you have to pick a card to get 3 times the same card?

Tags: probability

Imagine you have a deck of 52 different playing cards and you are picking random cards with putting them back into the deck. How many times would you have to pick **in average** until you had the same card three times (**any** card, **not** consecutively, but in total)?

I know that the maximum amount would be 105 times and I ran a python script to determine the result more or less accurate (which gave me a value of about 26).

Additionally:
How would you solve this for other values than 3 and 52?

I am currently in tenth grade so please expain, what you are doing.

Comment: $105$ is indeed the maximum possible.  With $n$ cards and looking for the first time you have any card $k$ times the maximum would be  $(k-1)\times n +1$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(a,b)$ to be the expected number of times required before we get three of the same card, given that we've already picked $a$ cards once and $b$ cards twice.

Then $f(a,b)$ is equal to $$\mathcal{P}(\text{pick unseen card}) (f(a+1, b)+1) + \mathcal{P}(\text{pick card we've seen once}) (f(a-1, b+1)+1) + \mathcal{P}(\text{pick card we've seen twice})$$
and we seek $f(0,0)$.
Indeed, imagine we're drawing the cards one by one. There are three options for a card we pick:

- We haven't seen the card before (which happens with probability $\mathcal{P}(\text{pick unseen card})$). Then we can't possibly have finished, but we do end up with one more card in our "I've seen this once already" bin, so $a$ goes up by $1$. Then we need to add $1$ to the expected $f(a+1,b)$ because we've just drawn a card, and without the $+1$, that card would never have been counted in our final tally.
- Much the same for the other two options: if we've seen the card exactly once, then the card moves from the "seen this once" bin to the "seen this twice" bin, while if we've seen the card exactly twice then we stop the procedure immediately because we've just drawn it for the third time.

Now the first probability is $\frac{52-a-b}{52}$; the second probability is $\frac{a}{52}$; the third is $\frac{b}{32}$. We know that $f(0, 52) = 1$.

This is a bit gnarly; the actual answer is about 25.9401, but it is precisely: $$\frac{1645516819072516747063954637515304730926161435623332999154274525929564\
9505490861837576575684186076658054263551685590992366866277401017025634\
19660086143279733}{
6343531956459445979564734158533832190194919794576289785420957627084061\
9705485642222459488609913885674958291073733995976497805216210585663433\
604198729515008}$$

Of course, I did this by Mathematica, but it can be done inductively. The function I used was:

```
Function[{x, y}, 
  Reduce[
    (52 - x - y)/52 (f[x + 1, y] + 1) + x/52 (f[x - 1, y + 1] + 1) + y/52 == f[x, y],
    {f[x, y]}]
  /. Equal -> Set]
@@@ Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, 52, 0, -1}, {x, 52 - y, 0, -1}], 1];

f[0,0]
```

The method generalises easily to $52 \not = 52$. For $3 \not = 3$, I'm afraid it just gets more and more disgusting: the recurrence will get longer and longer.

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression after "is equal to"? Also, why do we seek $f(0,0)$? Isn't this is "the expected number of times required before we get three of the same card, given that we've already picked $a$ ($=0$) cards once and $b$ ($=0$) cards twice"?

Comment: We seek $f(0,0)$ because we start out having picked no cards once and no cards twice, so $a=b=0$. I'll flesh out the expression a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the principle now. But could you please explain this last function? I never used a tool like 'Mathematica' before.

Comment: But you are saying that $f(0,0)\approx 25.9401$, right? Surely, when we arrive at three of the same kind, there is a very high probability that some other cards have been drawn once or twice, so $a,b\not=0$? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Think of it as a game: we start out with $a=b=0$, and we pick a card from the "never seen" bucket. We put that card into the "seen once" bucket. Then with some probability, we move into one of the two $(a,b) = (2,0), (0,1)$ cases, and so on. Our aim is to get into the case where we pick a card which is already in the "seen twice" bucket. $f$ is the expected number of draws given that the game has started in the position specified by $a$ and $b$; notice that we add $1$ after each transition in the main expression, so that $f$ is measuring time-steps rather than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where the "year" has 52 days and we want the expected number of trials until three people have the same birthday.  The general solution for the expected number of trials until $b$ persons have the same birthday on a planet with a year of $r$ days is
$$I(r,b) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} e_{b-1}\left(\frac{t}{r}\right)^r \; dt$$
where
$$e_b(x) = \sum_{i=0}^b \frac{1}{i!} x^i$$
Reference: [Analytic Combinatorics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi_hajMu5XUAhXD5SYKHTU3AQUQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Falgo.inria.fr%2Fflajolet%2FPublications%2Fbook.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGQzAeg_caEgKCAjqqwP8exYIqKuA&sig2=pAoGczS32Ldp6CA3oeQ_mQ) by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick, p. 116, equation (29).

We have the case $b=3$, $r=52$.  Numerical integration via Mathematica yields
$$I(52,3) \approx 25.9401$$
which agrees with the Monte Carlo result of "about 26" in the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I knew the problem would be quite similiar to the Birthday problem, but I didn't find a formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough but close approach, if you draw $n$ times from a $k$ card deck the chance you have drawn a particular card exactly three times is ${n \choose 3}\frac {(k-1)^{n-2}}{k^n}$  The chance you have not drawn any card three times is then $\left(1-{n \choose 3}\frac {(k-1)^{n-2}}{k^n}\right)^k$.  This is not quite right as it ignores the chance you have drawn a card four times and the correlations between the cards.  To get the number of draws to have $50\%$ chance of drawing a card three times, you can set this to $\frac 12$ and solve for $n$ numerically.  Getting the average number is harder because the correlations are ignored.  This would not say there was any number of draws that guarantees three of a kind, but $2k+1$ does guarantee that.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%20choose%203)51%5E(x-2)%2F52%5Ex%3D1%2F2) says for a $52$ card deck you hit the $50\%$ mark at $24.2$ cards.